# Jenkins pipeline selective delete

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm slowly replacing traditional jobs with Jenkins pipelines. We've got some jobs which I've previously optimised by only deleting some key files from the workspace of a previous build - thus we end up with incremental builds rather than full ones. FTR this makes our basic builds 3/4 times faster, and I'm keen to preserve it.

I need to delete those files (to simplify real scenario) that contain "cache". I currently use "**/*cache*" as an include parameter to the Delete Workspace build step. Question: is there something similar already in pipeline steps? I could probably do it using find or similar, but this has to work on Windows too and that has portability implications.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `cleanWS` step to clean up certain parts of the workspace. However, it is a plugin you can find here: [Workspace Cleanup Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Workspace+Cleanup+Plugin).

You can find syntax about a snippet generator for this step at `your-jenkins-url/pipeline-syntax/`

Answer (score 0):

I've switched away from using cleanWS having used it. Rather I am using the file operations to explicitly delete the files concerned.

The file operations act there and then. The cleanWs acts at the end of a run and can't be relied upon if that run went wrong and did not finish - e.g. syntax error - or that was running a different script.